# Does Azure mobile app support certificate based authentication between client and server

Tags: authentication, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to limit the access of azure mobile app service to ONLY my client apps, not others, API keys can limit some access, but anyone can do man in middle attack and get the api key, so I was wandering Does Azure mobile app support certificate based authentication between client and server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authentication mechanism in Mobile Apps SDK is implemented with OAuth 2.0 grand flow. However you can implement the certificate based authentication by yourself.

You can install certificate on Azure Mobile Apps the same as on Azure Web Apps, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site for more info.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I already bought the SSL certificate and it has already been setup at the CDN.  Can the oAuth and cert based live side by side. My scenario is. Only application developed my me, should be able to use the exposed APIs. Right now SSL cert only encrypts the data during transmission, but anyone can do reverse enginerring and call my service APIs

Comment: You can set your cert info in your each request header, and verify it on your server side before next progress.

Comment: Is there any example/tutorial/starting point to set it up, I was looking for examples at msdn but couldn't find any. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, currently, there is no such example. you can report your feature at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback